# PHP - Get the key that has a value in multiple indexes

Tags: php, laravel

I have the below array:

```php
$myArray = [
   [
     "name" => null,
     "price" => [
         "height" => 0.0098974902792506,
         "left" => 0.8385,
         "page" => 1,
         "top" => 0.51290208554259,
         "width" => 0.0275,
     ],
   ],
   [
     "name" => null
     "price" => [
         "height" => 0.0098974902792506,
         "left" => 0.838,
         "page" => 1,
         "top" => 0.56981265464829,
         "width" => 0.028,
     ]
   ],
   [
     "name" => null
     "price" => [
         "height" => 0.010250972074938,
         "left" => 0.5905,
         "page" => 1,
         "top" => 0.44114528101803,
         "width" => 0.0285,
     ]
   ]
];
```

I am trying to check the array and get the name of the **key** that has a value (is not `null`) in each array. In the above example, this would be `price`.

However, the array could also look like this:

```php
[
   [
     "name" => null,
     "price" => [
         "height" => 0.0098974902792506,
         "left" => 0.8385,
         "page" => 1,
         "top" => 0.51290208554259,
         "width" => 0.0275,
     ],
   ],
   [
     "name" => null
     "price" => null
   ],
   [
     "name" => null
     "price" => null
   ]
]
```

In this case, there is **not** an array key that has a value in all of the arrays.

Below is my attempt to achieve this:

```php
$originalKeyWithValue = null;
foreach($myArray as $key => $item)
{

  $originalKeyWithValue = array_key_first($item);
  if (isset($myArray[$key+1])) {
    $nextKeyWithValue = array_key_first($myArray[$key+1]);
  
    if($originalKeyWithValue != $nextKeyWithValue){
        $originalKeyWithValue = $nextKeyWithValue;
    }
    
  } 
}
return $originalKeyWithValue;
```

However the code above returns `name` as the key, even though it is `null` in all of the arrays in `$myArray`.

Comment: All names are null in your very first snippet, which one should the algorithm get? Or by `name of the key` you just mean the key?

Comment: There is no place in your code where you test if the value is `null`, that could explain it (note: `array_key_first` does not test null values, it returns null when the array is empty, that's totally different)

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy It should get `price` instead of `name`, as the `price` key has a value in all arrays.

Comment: What should happen if more than one key always has a value? And what should be returned if no keys have a value in all items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what would I do:

```
// I take first element of array as a source for indexes
foreach ($myArray[0] as $index => $item) {
    // next I extract all elements from all subarrays under current `$index`
    $values = array_column($myArray, $index);
    // then I filter values to remove nulls. 
    // This also removes 0, empty arrays, false, 
    // so maybe you should change filter process
    $values_filtered = array_filter($values);
    // if number of filtered items is same as in original array - no nulls found
    if (count($values_filtered) === count($values)) {
        echo $index;
        // optionally
        // break; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What an elegant and swift solution. This has really taught me something. Highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Although there is an accepted answer, I thought I would share a way to do this using Laravel collections.

```
 $uniqueKeysWithValues = collect($myArray)->map(function($item){
    return array_keys( collect($item)->filter()->toArray() ); //filter will remove all null
 })->flatten()->unique();
```

This approach will give you all keys that has values in it, even if there are values in both keys.

Comment: Highly appreciated!